How to call ChatGPT Assistants API v2 from Semantic Kernel in C#
I'd like to call a ChatGPT assistant I've created in Semantic Kernel.
I'd prefer to call the ChatGPT API directly rather than Azure but either will do.
I want to use an assistant not just call ChatGPT 4o because I want it to know about documents I  uploaded and how to act.
I found this page in the documentation, but the code doesn't work, eg it doesn't know what '...' is - perhaps that's a place holder but I've no idea what's supposed to go there (maybe the code is incomplete?)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/frameworks/agent/assistant-agent?pivots=programming-language-csharp
I've also found this video but instead of using the Assistants API v2 it just passes the 'how to act' text with every query which doesn't seem efficient and will use more tokens - it also doesn't allow for document uploading.
I'd like to use Semantic kernel for this but I can't find examples anywhere and the documentation seems incomplete.
Thanks

In Semantic Kernel you need to define the OpenAI settings before you use it. Please see the full example here Microsoft learn
